# generic way to form jdbcTemplate query in Dao

Tags: java, jdbc, dao, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have to use jdbcTemplate to have multiple different update query

I have an abstract base Dao layer

```
public abstract class MysqlBaseDao<V extends Serializable> {

public void update(V value) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(getUpdateQuery(), statementCallback(value));
}
```

with a service layer Dao

```
public class ServiceDao extends MysqlBaseDao<MyDataClass> {
    private static final String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE table SET `status` = ? WHERE `uuid` = ?";
    private static final String UPDATE_QUERY_BYID = "UPDATE table SET `status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";

    protected String getUpdateQuery() {
        return UPDATE_QUERY;
    }

    protected PreparedStatementCallback statementCallback(MyDataClass value){
        return statement -> {
        int i = 1;
        statement.setString(i++, value.getStatus());
        statement.setString(i++, value.getuuid());
        return statement.execute();
    };

}
```

Service layer

```
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceDao {
     public MyDataClass update(MyDataClass myDataClass) {
         ServiceDao.update(myDataClass);
     }
}
```

I want to be able to call both UPDATE_QUERY and UPDATE_QUERY_BYID from my service layer without individually mapping them

I have many versions of UPDATE QUERY so having them manually map is not an option